# Relation between semidirect product and direct product in the case that $N$ has two elements

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I am doing my thesis about semidirect products mainly and wondering how to solve the following question:

Let $G$ be a semidirect product of a normal subgroup $N$ with two elements by a subgroup $H$. Show that $G$ is an internal direct product of $N$ and $H$.

(I know that a semidirect prouct of $N$ by $H$ is the direct product if and only if the homomophism $H$ to $\operatorname{Aut}(N)$ is trivial, that is $\operatorname{id}(N)$ for all $h \in H$, but I dont really know how to move forward.)

Comment: I think you missed some typing or you meant something else: in your third line, what does "...of a group N *who two elements by* a subgroup H" mean?

Comment: Did you mean perhaps "N is a normal subgroup *with two elements*"?

Comment: sry corected it. yeah assumption would be N being normal.

Comment: How many automorphisms does $N$ have?

Comment: the question is in humphreys a course in group theory chapter 19 question 4. I dont understand the solution fully and also would like to show it some other way if possible.

Answer (score 1):

You know that semidirect products $C_2\rtimes H$ require a homomorphism $\phi:H\rightarrow\text{Aut}C_2$.  The product is direct if the homomorphism is trivial.  Now, let's figure out the automorphisms of $C_2$.  Any homomorphism $\theta$ preserves the identity, so $\theta:C_2\rightarrow C_2$ takes $\theta(1)=1$.  Furthermore, any automorphism is bijective, so the only other element of $C_2$ (its generator) must be mapped to itself by $\theta$.  Thus for any automorphism $\theta$, $\theta(x)=x$ for both $x\in C_2$, so $\text{Aut}C_2$ only consists of the trivial homomorphism.  Thus any semidirect product must be trivial.